# AWS Lambda can't find pyyaml from Lambda layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, pyyaml

I have a similar issue as reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389424/cant-import-yaml-module-from-aws-lambda-layer) but the solution mentioned there isn't working for me.

`UPDATE: Added list of files in package to the question`

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv pyyaml
$ source pyyaml/bin/activate
$ pip install pyyaml -t ./python
$ deactivate
$ zip -r layer-PyYAML.zip ./python/
$ aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name PyYAML --description "PyYAML" --compatible-runtimes python3.6 python3.7 python3.8 python3.9 --zip-file fileb://layer-PyYAML.zip
```

The last command runs successfully and gives me the ARN of the layer version. I use this to update the lambda:

```sh
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <lambda-function-name> --layers arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<AWS ACCOUNT ID>:layer:PyYAML
```

This also works and I can see the layer successfully added to the lambda function, but when I try to run the function I get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyyaml'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "ad37d387-...",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Here are the contents of the layer package:

```
$ tar -tf layer-PyYAML.zip
python/
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/RECORD
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/LICENSE
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/WHEEL
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/REQUESTED
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
python/PyYAML-6.0.dist-info/METADATA
python/_yaml/
python/_yaml/__init__.py
python/yaml/
python/yaml/scanner.py
python/yaml/error.py
python/yaml/constructor.py
python/yaml/composer.py
python/yaml/events.py
python/yaml/__init__.py
python/yaml/representer.py
python/yaml/tokens.py
python/yaml/dumper.py
python/yaml/cyaml.py
python/yaml/parser.py
python/yaml/reader.py
python/yaml/loader.py
python/yaml/resolver.py
python/yaml/serializer.py
python/yaml/nodes.py
python/yaml/emitter.py
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

You use pyyaml as:

```
import yaml
```

not

```
import pyyaml
```

Comment: I am importing it as `yaml`, I still get that error.

Comment: @hyperwiser What error? You can't get same error.

Comment: the error I mentioned in my question:
`"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyyaml'"`

Comment: @hyperwiser Then you are invoking some wrong function. Its NOT possible to get error `No module named 'pyyaml'` if you use `import yaml`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am invoking the right function :-)

Comment: @hyperwiser I will say again, you can't get error about No module named 'pyyaml'. Its simply not possible if you use `import yaml` in your code.

Comment: @Marcin "import yaml" won't work either, you will get "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'yaml'" error because yaml is not part of the lambda dependencies, hyperwiser has told you about 3 times but you don't seem to understand.